# Inputs inside ListView doesn't change values from old to recently set on ItemUpdating event

Tags: .net, events, listview, controls

I would appreciate if someone help me to understand this situation.
I do not know why but when i edit selected ListView item (containing few TextBoxes) and then press Update button **in the ItemUpdating event i always get old values instead of those which were typed recently. 
Why?**

1. I do not use Page_Load event so i do not need check on PostBack
2. I try to get value before i bind data from DB to ListView, so it can't override recently typed values
3. I tried to get TextBoxes values in different Event handlers - ItemCommand, ItemUpdating, ItemDataBound - result si always the same
4. Collection NewValues and OldValues are always empty (i think this is because i don't use SqlDataSource control)
5. The only one way i can get new values - is to check Request, but in this case i can't use control validators ... so probably it is bad idea to work with only request.

This is the code of ItemUpdating method:

```
    ListViewItem editItem = AdminUsersListView.EditItem;
    Guid userId = new Guid((editItem.FindControl("UserId") as HiddenField).Value);
    Hashtable dataUpdate = new Hashtable
    {
        { "UserName", Request[ (editItem.FindControl("UserNameNew") as TextBox).UniqueID ] },
        { "Email", Request[ (editItem.FindControl("Email") as TextBox).UniqueID ] },
        { "IsApproved", Request[ (editItem.FindControl("IsApproved") as CheckBox).UniqueID ] == "on" },
        { "IsLockedOut", Request[ (editItem.FindControl("IsLockedOut") as CheckBox).UniqueID ] == "on" }
    };


var x1 = dataUpdate["UserName"];  // this is corrent new value from Request
var x2 = (editItem.FindControl("UserNameNew") as TextBox).Text;  // this is WRONG! OLD! value from TextBox ... Why???

    using (Entities entities = new Entities())
    {
        aspnet_Membership membershipItem = entities.aspnet_Membership.Where(MBS => MBS.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
        membershipItem.Email = dataUpdate["Email"].ToString();
        membershipItem.LoweredEmail = membershipItem.Email.ToLower();
        membershipItem.IsApproved = Convert.ToBoolean(dataUpdate["IsApproved"]);
        membershipItem.IsLockedOut = Convert.ToBoolean(dataUpdate["IsLockedOut"]);
        entities.SaveChanges();
        aspnet_Users userItem = entities.aspnet_Users.Where(USR => USR.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
        userItem.UserName = dataUpdate["UserName"].ToString();
        userItem.LoweredUserName = userItem.UserName.ToLower();
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    AdminUsersListView.EditIndex = -1;
    AdminUsersListView.DataSource = _getDataList();
    AdminUsersListView.DataBind();
```

Thanks, Art

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the answer ... F***ING VIEWSTATE!!!

Be aware of this!
To get data always actual you need to set EnableViewState to "False".

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState="False"
         Language="C#" 
         MasterPageFile="~/App_Masters/Admin.Master" 
         AutoEventWireup="true" 
         CodeBehind="Users.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="WebShop.Admin.Users" %>
```

The trick is that setting this just for specific input is not enough! This helped me only after i set this for whole page in ASPX.